# In-role, co-located caching & CacheService.exe

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-caching, azure-in-role-cache

We utilise Azure's co-located In-Role caching in our web roles.

When looking at memory usage in Window's Resource Monitor, I see that a "CacheService.exe" is consuming a large portion of available RAM:

[image: CacheService.exe]

Is this the cache cluster used by the in-role cache?  And can I roughly assume the total, cumulative size of all my cached objects by looking at CacheService.exe's memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CacheService.exe is the executable for In-Role cache. If this is causing bottleneck for your application, you should consider using dedicated In-Role cache instead of an In-Role one.

Comment: And can I roughly assume the total, cumulative size of all my cached objects by looking at CacheService.exe's memory usage?

Comment: Yes, that should be a good approximation for getting size of all your cached objects. A couple of things to note 1) Your objects will be distributed across the nodes in cache cluster, 2) Memory usage will also include overhead for maintaining the data partition logic.